# AjaxToolKitCalendarExtender Set Initial View Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the AjaxToolKit Calendar Extender in my application so the user can select their date of birth. Most users that will be using the system will be over the age of 60 so i want this to appear as the default view when the textbox contains no text, i have set the calendar to open up in year mode, but i am unable to get to default to a date 60 years in the past without having anything in the associated textbox.

what i am trying to achieve is what is the picture but when the user open the calendar extender when the textbox contains no values.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ccStars Try a combination of `DefaultView`, `SelectedDate` and `PopupButtonID`.

`DefaultView`: will take you to the year mode which you have already done.
`SelectedDate`: will set a date the calendar is initialized with,
`PopupButtonID`: *the id of a control to show the calendar popup when clicked. If this value is not set, the calendar will pop up when the textbox receives focus*. So have a small calendar icon next to your textbox and give its id. This will solve your problem of getting a date only when it is selected in the calendar.

Above are server-side properties. The client-side properties of your interest are:

`selectedDate` and `visibleDate`: the difference is that the `selectedDate` is the value represented by the textbox, but `visibleDate` is the date currently visible in calendar.

More information here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_calendar_reference.ashx

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Calendar's `SelectedDate` attribute, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  calendarExtender.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-60);
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried that and it outputs the date in the textbox which i don't want, the date should only appeat in the textbox if it has been selected/specified by the user

Comment: I see. Your best bet in that case would be to do some client-side scripting to manually set the decade to the value you require. Either that, or you can download the source code for the extender and change it to suit your needs.

Comment: Im not sure how you do this via Javascript i have looked on the internet but have been unable to find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

I know there's not a clear way of doing this, but what if we tried some jury-rigging and testing?

If you set the `SelectedDate` using Cobra's answer above, I'm assuming it will default to the right date range.

Now, if afterwards, on the client-side, you did some JavaScript to clear out the `TextBox`, I wonder if the `CalendarExtender` would still keep the old date ranges?

Using jQuery, here's a quick script to do it.  Assumption is that the `TextBox`'s `ID` is `txtDateOfBirth` and the `ClientIDMode` is set to `Static`.

```
$('#txtDateOfBirth').val('');
```